# R - simple summary export to Latex

Tags: r, latex, summary, xtable

let's imagine the following vector:

```
test <- c(21.63318,NaN,NaN,24.03223,NaN,NaN,19.18797,NaN,17.71838)
```

I do a simple summary:

```
sum.test <- summary(test)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  17.72   18.82   20.41   20.64   22.23   24.03       5
```

I wouldlike to export the table as it is to latex. I tried:

```
print(xtable(as.table(sum.test), type = "latex"), file = "test.tex")
```

But I obtain:

[image]

Is their a way to have it horizontal (as displayed in R), without the "x"?

Comment: I get Error with your code `xtable(as.array(test), type = "latex")`

Comment: Your figure shows the summary.  So, i am confused

Comment: From which package is your `xtable` function? There are more than one, maybe try with others?

Comment: Have you tried transposing? `xtable(t(summary(1:8)))`

Comment: Also maybe: `data.frame(x=test); xtable(summary(values))`, sorry I can't check this atm.

Comment: @AkselA ! very good point! but I a line number (1) in the final latex display, do you know a way to cancel it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Is it something like `knitr::kable(t(summary(test)),"latex")`?

Comment: @yarnabrina Yes, something like that, auto exported in a .tex file, which include a table environment. (And without the vertical lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, `include.rownames=FALSE` does the trick.

```
library(xtable)
print(xtable(t(summary(1:8))), type="html", file="xt.html", include.rownames=FALSE)
```

```html
<!-- html table generated in R 3.5.0 by xtable 1.8-2 package -->
<!-- Tue May  7 17:59:59 2019 -->
<table border=1>
<tr> <th> Min. </th> <th> 1st Qu. </th> <th> Median </th> <th> Mean </th> <th> 3rd Qu. </th> <th> Max. </th>  </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 1.00 </td> <td align="right"> 2.75 </td> <td align="right"> 4.50 </td> <td align="right"> 4.50 </td> <td align="right"> 6.25 </td> <td align="right"> 8.00 </td> </tr>
   </table>
```